# Remove element from an AngularJS template

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create an AngularJS template, but during development I would like to set it to have some stylesheets that I use which I would put in a  section of the template, and preferably have a proper HTML file which contains a body as well, but that can come later.

So I would like to have the following HTML file

```
<head>
<link
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<h1>H1</h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    Some text goes here?
</div>
</div>
```

but when I render it *anytime* I use templateUrl, I would like the head section removed.  Or preferably, only include things in `<body>` given the following HTML template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>H1</h1>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        Some text goes here?
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My initial guess is something like this, but this didn't seem to work.

```
directive("head", [ '$rootScope', '$compile',
function($rootScope, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: ""
    }
}
]);
```

Comment: one simple solution is use server side includes for the full page and for templateUrl point at partials

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like what you're looking for is a [ui-view](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). (Look at Nested States & Views section for further info). It allows you to have a special element

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

Where you can load different HTMLs into depending on your current state of the angular application.

You can also go with [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude). This is a directive which will render an HTML for you.

Will look like this:

```
<div ng-include="MyPage.html"></div>
```

And you will have this for instance:

```
// MyPage.html
<div>
   Whatever you want goes here, and no need for a head element
</div>
```

Comment: Nope that does not satisfy my requirement, I want the included file to contain the elements I want to exclude not the other way around of including the them through another file.